# Why does error message created by JS dorm validation function disappear after a short time in my html site

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

Why does error message created by JS dorm validation function disappear after a short time in my html site

i have a website with a registration page in which when you click the "submit" button a JS function validates all of the needed fields if a certein field is invalid it an error massage is spoused to appear and stay until the client change it , but in reality it appears for like half a second and then dissapears .

the html file is also connected to a C# page which uploads the indormation to the server , for the JS and C# not to clash i use a "onsubmit" function.

JS code :

```
function RegisterVerification() {
    let uName = document.getElementById("uName").value;
    let fName = document.getElementById("fName").value;
    let lName = document.getElementById("lName").value;
    let passwd = document.getElementById("passwd").value;
    let email = document.getElementById("email").value;
    let phone = document.getElementById("phone").value;


    var isValid = true;

    if (containsNumbers(fName) == true || fName.length < 2 || containsSpecialChars(fName) == true) {
        document.getElementById("fNameErorr").innerHTML = "first name invalid"
        isValid = false;
    }

    if (containsNumbers(lName) == true || lName.length < 3 || containsSpecialChars(lName) == true) {
        document.getElementById("lNameErorr").innerHTML = "last name invalid"
        isValid = false;
    }

    if (uName.length < 5 || containsNumbers(uName) == false) {
        document.getElementById("uNameErorr").innerHTML = "username invalid"
        isValid = false;
    }

    if (containsNumbers(passwd) == false || passwd.length < 8 || containsSpecialChars(passwd) == false) {
        document.getElementById("passwdErorr").innerHTML = "password invalid "
        isValid = false;
    }

    if (ValidateEmail(email) == false) {
        document.getElementById("emailErorr").innerHTML = "email invalid"
        isValid = false;
    }

    if (phoneRegex(phone) == false) {
        document.getElementById("phoneErorr").innerHTML = "email invalid"
        isValid = false;
    }


    return (isValid)

}
```

relevant html code :

```
<form id="mainform" runat="server"  onsubmit="return RegisterVerification()">

        <label class="tabletext" for="uName">User name</label>
        <input type="text" id="uName" name="uName" />
        <h4 class="erorr" id="uNameErorr"></h4>

        <label class="tabletext" for="passwd">Password</label>
        <input type="text" id="passwd" name="passwd" />
        <h4 class="erorr" id="passwdErorr"></h4>

        <label class="tabletext" for="lName">Last name</label>
        <input type="text" id="lName" name="lName" />
        <h4 class="erorr" id="lNameErorr"></h4>

        <label class="tabletext" for="fName">First name</label>
        <input type="text" id="fName" name="fName" />
        <h4 class="erorr" id="fNameErorr"></h4>


        <label class="tabletext" for="phone">Phone Number</label>
        <input type="text" id="phone" name="phone" />
        <h4 class="erorr" id="phoneErorr"></h4>

        <label class="tabletext" for="email">Email</label>
        <input type="text" id="email"  name="email" />
        <h4 class="erorr" id="emailErorr"></h4>


        <input id="registerbutton" type="submit" name="send"  />


    </form>
```